# Change POST requests to PATCH via Apache httpd proxy

Tags: apache, proxy

Is there any way to change the POST verb to PATCH via Apache httpd proxy ?

We are trying to call to Rest API (PATCH method) via Oracle SOA 12c rest adapter but unable to call it as PATCH verb is not supported by Oracle SOA version we are using.